# How to determine the angular frequency of phasor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

If I've got a voltage/intensity generator expressed in complex numbers, how can I determine \$w\$ to calculate the impedances?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Is it something I should understand?

Comment: In an exercise instead of having a sinusoidal equation as source, i had a complex number. Just a teacher's error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't determine it. It has to be given or assumed.